# Transaction scope function

Tags: c#, transactionscope

I am using the below code to apply the transaction scope

```
TransactionOptions transOption = new TransactionOptions();
transOption.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted;

using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transOption))
{
  //Code to delete    
  //Code to insert

  scope.Complete();
}
```

the scope is not working where if I have an error in the insert the record is deleted not rolled back

Comment: can you show the code you use to delete and also, tell us the database server you are using?

Comment: If you insert a record... and there's an error... and it gets deleted but not rolled back... are you sure you're not looking at a record that's been inserted, and then the transaction's being rolled back?? The rollback will "delete" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to tell us which database server you are using. and if you are getting any exception messages or not

anyway the code seems correct, did you check the (MSDTC)? check if it's enabled on your OS.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete.aspx states:

TransactionScope.Complete() Indicates that all operations within the scope are completed successfully.

So unless your "Code to Insert" is throwing an exception which terminates the Using block, your code is always calling scope.Complete() and committing your database changes.

If your "Code to Delete" and "Code to Insert" are handling exceptions internally, then they need to return info to your Using block to indicate whether or not everthing worked. For example, assuming your "code" blocks are method calls that return true if all good or false if failed, you can write:

```
bool allGood;

allGood = CodeToDelete();

if(allGood)
{
  allGood = CodeToInsert();
}

if(allGood)
{
  scope.Complete();
}
```